# C win32 - How can I select a file at random from a folder?

Tags: c, file

I have a **c:\config** folder which contains several configuration files (config_x).
I would like to be able to choose one of them at random (the program is written in C).
The number of files may change in the future - so needs to be able to query for number of files in the folder.

How can it be done?

Comment: Go through your old questions and put a green check on the best answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks! will do that right away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` in a loop. Keep a count of how many files you've seen so far (`n`). On each loop, randomly break out on a `1:n` chance:

```
if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE!=(hFind = FindFirstFile(DirSpec, &FindFileData))) {
    for(i=0;;++i) {
        strcpy(fileChoice, FindFileData.cFileName);
        while(rand_s(&r));
        if( ((double)r) / ((double)i) < 1.0 ) break;
        if(!FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData)) break;
    }
}
```

You can find a proof of this method in The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.4.2, by Donald E. Knuth.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` to build a list of the  files in the folder
- Generate a random number between 0 and the number of files and then pick that index from the list

MSDN has [an example on listing files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @aaaa: Using the example above, you can place a `int counter=rand()` and `FindNextFile` for the `counter` number of times, and then `break` the loop.

Comment: @KMån Yes, but what do you do if there are fewer files than `counter` ? If you always choose the last file you have a good chance of choosing it more often than the others.

Comment: @geocar, it does. Perhaps a combined solution would be best. Choose a random number, see if the number of files is smaller and if so choose another random number.

Comment: that's slow. My answer uses a fixed amount of memory, and gets the correct answer on less than a single pass through the list of files.